# alsamixer USB Headphone/MIC combo cannot control mic

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I have attempted everything i have been able to scour the internet for and am at a loss. HyperX Cloud Flight S headphones will not allow me to use the mic whereas their previous non-s revision works perfectly. Here are some relevant outputs:

```
uname -a
Linux laptop 5.3.0-42-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 05:49:40 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
amixer -c1 contents
numid=4,iface=CARD,name='Keep Interface'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=on
numid=7,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Switch',index=1
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
amixer: Control hw:1 element read error: Invalid argument

numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=8,min=0,max=74,step=0
  : values=54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54
  | dBminmax-min=-74.00dB,max=0.00dB
numid=8,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Volume',index=1
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=1,step=0
amixer: Control hw:1 element read error: Invalid argument

numid=9,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Capture Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
amixer: Control hw:1 element read error: Invalid argument

numid=10,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Capture Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=1,min=0,max=1,step=0
amixer: Control hw:1 element read error: Invalid argument

numid=5,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=1,min=0,max=36,step=0
  : values=0
  | container
    | chmap-fixed=MONO

numid=1,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=2,min=0,max=36,step=0
  : values=3,4
  | container
    | chmap-fixed=FL,FR
    | chmap-fixed=FL,FR,FC,LFE,SL,SR,SL,SR

numid=6,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map',device=1
  ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=2,min=0,max=36,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | container
    | chmap-fixed=FL,FR
```

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0951:16ea Kingston Technology HyperX Cloud Flight S
```

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
1 [S              ]: USB-Audio - HyperX Cloud Flight S
                      Kingston HyperX Cloud Flight S at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, full speed
```

```
arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: S [HyperX Cloud Flight S], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [kernel update](https://lkml.org/lkml/2020/4/4/197) in 5.7rc3 introduced a patch for this issue (for this headset specifically). Once patched your dmesg output should have a line that looks like:

```
[    6.804026] kernel: usb 1-1: Found post-registration device assignment: 095116ea:02
```

The alsa configuration documentation states:

```
Module snd-usb-audio
--------------------
...
delayed_register
    The option is needed for devices that have multiple streams
    defined in multiple USB interfaces.  The driver may invoke
    registrations multiple times (once per interface) and this may
    lead to the insufficient device enumeration.
    This option receives an array of strings, and you can pass
    ID:INTERFACE like ``0123abcd:4`` for performing the delayed
    registration to the given device.  In this example, when a USB
    device 0123:abcd is probed, the driver waits the registration
    until the USB interface 4 gets probed.
    The driver prints a message like "Found post-registration device
    assignment: 1234abcd:04" for such a device, so that user can
    notice the need.
```

So taking the above information you get from dmesg, and the field you need from the config docs, add this to the end of alsa-base.conf

```
# Add delayed register for HyperX Cloud Flight S Headset
options snd-usb-audio delayed_register=095116ea:02
```

Then reboot and you should be able to see the headset and profiles as expected.

As a side note, there is another option in the snd-usb-audio module

```
quirk_alias
    Quirk alias list, pass strings like ``0123abcd:5678beef``, which
    applies the existing quirk for the device 5678:beef to a new
    device 0123:abcd.
```

This would lead me to believe that you could copy the quirk that already was written by kernel 5.4 for "Kingston HyperX AMP" and apply it to this headset, as well as adding the delayed register and it would work pre 5.7. As i already bit the bullet and did the kernel upgrade i am not going to go back and check. If someone gets that working please let me know and ill update the post here. It should be as straight forward as:

```
options snd-usb-audio quirk_alias=095116ea:095116d8 delayed_register=095116ea:02
```

Let me know!